# How to stop being logged out on Twitter in Google Chrome?

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, twitter

I am using Windows 10 20H2 and Google Chrome 88.0.4324.182. To this day, I still have no idea why I would be logged out of Twitter automatically after a few days (only Twitter, other sites still stay logged in as normal). It's very frustrating because my Twitter account has two-factor authentication set up, and I know that in no way does this problem relate to Twitter's end.

I've tried to reinstall Google Chrome before, and it worked. I didn't get logged out anymore. The downside is all of the settings of my extensions are cleared. Google Sync only syncs the extensions, without syncing the settings. You probably will wonder if my extensions caused this problem. This is the list of my extensions:

- Bypass Paywalls
- Dark Reader
- Extension Manager
- Google Translate
- Grammarly for Chrome
- Honey
- IDM Integration Module
- Pop up blocker for Chrome
- Tampermonkey (I only use this to download scores from Musescore)
- Universal Bypass
- uBlock origin
- BetterTTV
- MAL-Sync
- MEGA
- Twitch Tools

After the reinstallation, I used Twitter normally for a few months, then this problem appeared again today.

Comment: Disable all extensions, enable them one at a time after logging into twitter, use the browser for a few days and enable one more, do this until you find the one causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Getting logged out of Twitter means the cookies are getting deleted.

1. chrome://settings/cookies?search=setting
2. Ensure that "clear cookies and data" is unchecked.
3. Add Twitter to sites that can always use cookies.

If you clear out your cache, you'll have to log into Twitter again. Twitter deletes your cookies occasionally, as stated in their [privacy policy](https://twitter.com/en/privacy), this could be another reason why you're logged out.